# How to Connect Azure open AI account from function app using managed identity by providing RBAC roles to Azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity, azure-openai

Scenario:
I have Azure open AI model in higher environment and we don't have access for the open AI key directly. So was trying to connect open AI model using function app by using managed identity, and providing "Cognitive Services User" in open AI for function app.

How to implement this using python code in function app?

Comment: could you share you code / what you've tried so far?

Comment: This article explains most of what you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/managed-identity#authorize-access-to-managed-identities

Comment: Thank you Thomas, it worked with the the code explaination provided in the github link provided in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76439217/using-managed-identity-to-access-azure-openai-service?rq=2 question.

Comment: Good to hear that it is working for you now :-)